# Is this Fractal New?

Tags: fractals, symmetry

I developed some equations relating to symmetry.  When used recursively, they produce what I believe is a fractal of symmetries.  The fractal is procedurally generated like a snowflake or a gasket, but it produces an image that looks more like a Mandelbrot.

Does anyone recognize my results?  Any info would be appreciated.

[This image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WoVg3sXof-UkdCdmowNy1sUTA/view) goes down 11 generations.

[image: Sigma and Delta functions only]

It's 10,000x10,000 so you can zoom in. I'm still working on a good palette mapping scheme.  I think there's a lot more structure in there than is currently visible.

If anyone is interested in the math, I have posted a paper [here](http://adventuresinkapland.blogspot.com/).  I am interested in publishing formally, but need an endorser.

So, is this novel or can someone point me to what I've duplicated?  If not, does anyone have any thoughts?  Any help is much appreciated.

(I am posting this question based on advice in the answer found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508014/journals-that-publish-papers-quickly))

Update: The fractal was only half-there. I discovered the other half. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-WoVg3sXof-T2hUanpVVElEM1E&authuser=0) is a pic in case it is more recognizable.  There are pics of a few different generations on my blog.

[image: Sigma/Delta functions and their new counterparts]

(Thanks VividD for the embedded pic, I followed suit!)

Comment: In general, using this site to announce something potentially  new with the question, "Is this new?" is generally frowned upon. If you have a specific question, rather than merely self-promotion of some work, then you should ask those.

Comment: It's awful nice to look at, and it wouldn't shock me if it's not been looked at before (though perhaps it has). However, as far as *linear* transformations go, it  has the same symmetries as a square - which you can ascertain by looking at it and with a little bit of algebra - and as far as more general symmetries, it has the same properties as most any fractal made similarly - essentially, one symmetry per point in the fractal. I think you'd need to demonstrate some particular interest in this case to make it more than a pretty picture. (Not that there's anything wrong with pretty pictures)

Comment: Thomas: I appreciate the information. I was only following the instructions in the answer I referenced. I had already set up a blog with my stuff, but it recommended asking here if my idea was novel before trying to publish formally. As I am not an academic, I have no peers. As this is my only option, I am unapologetic.  Cheers.

Comment: Meelo: Thanks! It just got a whole lot better, though. If you go to my blog, I have posted an update. The image in my OP is only half of the picture. Now, it is really something to behold.

Comment: Might try posting to https://www.reddit.com/r/fractals/  and also look for it in the major fractal programs.